# I'm looking for "The Cannonball Fallacy."

Tags: bias, cognition

The "shell fallacy" as I see it is this: someone walks into a crater created by a shell on the battlefield and says, "There's no way any more shells are going to fall here. "No more shells should fall here."
I think this fallacy had a different name than the gambler's fallacy.
If anyone knows, please let me know.

They are essentially the same thing, but I remember reading about them in some online article as clearly differentiated, time-honored examples.

Comment: I'm curious what you think might distinguish this from the gambler's fallacy. An alternative framing that's a familiar idiom is: "lightning never strikes twice in the same place" of course.

Comment: I have not heard of the fallacy you described but there is similar called the *Conjunction Fallacy* - see https://www.bramleylab.ppls.ed.ac.uk/pdfs/ludwinpeery2020broken.pdf